# Getting TrustedHTML assignment error in Visualforce page

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce, visualforce, sfdc

I am getting This document requires 'TrustedHTML' assignment error in jquery 3.6.0 in visualforce page after adding CSP in response header

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXj9D.png)

[Response Header Screensshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aX280.png)

Any guide will be helpful.
Thank you